# Some more syntactic sugar with the "with" statement?

Tags: php

I like PHP, but I miss some of the constructs from other languages that although don't do anything for performance, make the code look cleaner and possibly more maintainable. I'm thinking of Visual Basic days and the "with" statement.

So ideally in PHP we could do this:

```
with($myWellDescribedInstance) {
    ->property1="string";
    ->property2=1;
    ->property3=2;
    ->myMethod();
}
```

Instead of

```
$myWellDescribedInstance->property1="string";
$myWellDescribedInstance->property2=1;
$myWellDescribedInstance->property3=2;
$myWellDescribedInstance->myMethod();
```

Is there anything like this in PHP?

Comment: If you just use `$WDI` the PHP would be even shorter than the `with`.

Comment: It's a personal preference @AbraCadaver I guess, but there is nothing worse than having to modify code (especially someone else's) where all identifiers are acronyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) on any class just by having a function return `$this`.
This is mostly used for setters, but of course it works for any method for which you would normally not have a return value.

For example:

```
class Person
{
    protected $name = '';
    protected $surname = '';
    protected $email = '';

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$person = new Person;
$person->setName('John')
    ->setSurname('Doe')
    ->setEmail('johndoe@email.com');
```

Of course, calling the method (for example) `setName` or `withName` would be entirely up to you.

Another idea might be to have *both* a `setName` method (which doesn't return anything) *and* a `withName` method (which returns `$this`), but that might be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Thank you, that's probably the best answer I will get, but this raises that age old PHP debate of public access v getters and setters. I've gone with the former!

Comment: @JAMMac IMO direct public access is just straight up evil :D Setters and getters all the way for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you use "setters" instead of direct property access you can chain methods.

```php
class A {
    private $a;
    private $b;

    public function setA($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setB($b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
        return $this;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {}
}

$a = new A();
$a->setA('a')
  ->setB('b')
  ->doSomething();
```